# javascript onmouseover change background image

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

I need to create simple photo gallery with JavaScript. 
My code doesn't works

```
function upDate(previewPic){
document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "url('previewPic.src')";
document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = previewPic.alt;
```

In this function I should 
     change the URL for the background image of the div with the `id="image"` 
    to the source file of the preview image

HTML code:

```
<body>  
<div id="image">
    Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
<img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
<img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function upDate(previewPic){
   var src = previewPic.getAttribute( "src" );
   var alt = previewPic.getAttribute( "alt" );
   document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + src + "')";
   document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = alt;
}

  function unDo(X){
   X = document.getElementById('image');
   X.style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "Hover over an image below to display here";
  
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 2%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
#image{
    line-height:650px;
  width: 575px;
    height: 650px;
  border:5px solid black;
  margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #8e68ff;
    background-image: url('');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    font-size: 150%;
}
.preview{
  width:10%;
  margin-left:17%;
    border: 10px solid black;
}
img{
  width:95%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Photo Gallery</title>
 </head>
<body>
 
 <div id = "image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
 </div>
 
 <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
 
 <img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
 
 <img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any idea how to include onmouseout="unDo()">

Comment: I made it! But can anybody explain the JS coding for me please!

Answer (score 1):

```
function upDate(previewPic){

    document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage="url('" + previewPic.src + "')"; 
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML=previewPic.alt;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
function upDate(previewPic)
{
   var src = previewPic.getAttribute( "src" );
   var alt = previewPic.getAttribute( "alt" );
   document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + src + "')";
   document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = alt;
}
```

Comment: It's work correctly with image. But create a variable for "alt"  - not necessary. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo with the intent to show what you needed corrected and I kept adding, sorry. You'll find the recommended changes below. The reason why the images do not match what's hovered on is because the source of the images are dynamic. It'll function properly with your static images.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>34516675</title>
<style>
section { padding: 10%; }
figure { margin: 0 auto; }
#frame { background-image: url('data:image/gif; base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAA='); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-clip:border-box; background-size:contain; width: 480px; height: 270px; border: 1px solid blue; margin: 0 auto; }
.preview { cursor:pointer; }
figcaption{ text-align: center; font: small-caps 400 16px/1.45 "Palatino Linotype"; }
 #gallery { width: 490px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>  
<section>
<figure>
<div id="frame"></div>
    <figcaption id="caption"></figcaption>
</figure>

<figure id="gallery">
<figcaption>Hover over an image below to display above.</figcaption>
<img class="preview" id="pic1" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://placeimg.com/160/90/tech" onmclick="upDate(1)">

<img class="preview" id="pic2" alt="With My Boy" src="https://placeimg.com/160/90/people" onclick="upDate(2)">

<img class="preview" id="pic3" src="https://placeimg.com/160/90/animals" alt="Young Puppy" onclick="upDate(3)">
</figure>
</section>
<script>
var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');
gallery.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        var target = e.target.id;
        upDate(target);
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);

function upDate(target){
 var tgt = document.getElementById(target);
 var src = tgt.src;
 var alt = tgt.alt;
 var fig = document.getElementById('frame');
 var cap = document.getElementById('caption');
 fig.style.backgroundImage = "url("+src+")";
  cap.innerHTML = alt;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function upDate(previewPic){
  var src = previewPic.getAttribute("src");
  var alt = previewPic.getAttribute("alt");
  document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + src + "')";
  document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = alt;
}

function unDo(){
  document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "none";
  document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "Hover over an image below to display here";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function upDate(previewPic){
      document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = 
      "url('" +previewPic.src + "')";
      document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = previewPic.alt;
}

function unDo(X){
     document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "url('')"; 
     document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "Hover over an image 
     below to display here";
}
```